# Find content after a specifc bracket using java

Tags: java

I want to find if a bracket contains a specific word. If that word is found, I want to get the single quote next to that particular bracket.

Here is my try:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.regex.Matcher;
 import java.util.regex.Pattern;

 class Test 
 {
        public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException 
        {
        String content ="(content1)'first' is the first to find then  (content2)'second' and so on";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(content);
          while(m.find()) 
          {
              if(m.group(1).contains("content2")) 
              {  
                   System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
                  //it gives content2,want to get 'second'
              }
          }
       }
   }
```

Problem: I found the specific word inside the bracket. Now, how do I get the single quotes word after that particular bracket using java?

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: i think now the format is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can handle your requirement using a negative lookbehind which asserts that `(content2)` appears immediately before the word in single quotes:

```
(?<=\(content2\))'(.*?)'
```

Then, the word you actually want should be available in the first capture group.  Here is a working script:

```
String content ="(content1)'first' is the first to find then
    (content2)'second' and so on";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\(content2\\))'(.*?)'").matcher(content);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you soo much...this is what i want:)

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex (`content2` followed by a group with `'\w+'`) like below should work:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(content2\\)('\\w+')").matcher(content);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // it gives 'second'
}
```

Comment: Yes..Thank you :)

Comment: i have a doubt.this case will work only if exact content2 matched.what to do if bracket text starts with the word content2

Comment: @priya can you paste such input string here?

Comment: (content2_con).  and   (content2_c.+o_a.b.+n_b.b.h)  i have strings like this

Comment: @priya use this in that case `Pattern.compile("\\(content2.*\\)('\\w+')")`

Comment: Let me try this